# Вопрос по стилю программирования

Tags: c++

Для избежания создания лишних объектов, теоретического увеличения скорости программы(если объекты будут большими) я всегда стараюсь использовать ссылки при передаче параметров в функцию и их возврате из функции.
Например:

```
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, three_cl &obj);
```

Ход мысли правильный?

Т.е. такая версия предыдущей функции хуже:

```
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream stream, three_cl obj);
```

Конструктором копии тут создаются 2 объекта: `stream` и `obj`, которые уничтожатся при выходе из функции перегрузки оператора.

Если результат будет тот же, лучше использовать ссылки?

Comment: Преждевременная оптимизация источник всех зол. На данный момент компилятор берет на себя большую часть оптимизации вашего кода. Поэтому для начала сделайте релиз альфа/бета/релиз версию своей программы, а уже после проверьте хватает ли ее скорости. И тогда принимайтесь за оптимизацию.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, этот оператор

```
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream stream, three_cl obj);
```

некорректный. Класс `std::ostream` имеет удаленный конструктор копирования. Поэтому вы не можете передать объект класса `std::ostream` по значению. И кроме того из объявления функции получается, что функция возвращает ссылку на локальный объект `std::ostream`, что приводит к неопределенному поведению программы.

Конечно для определенных пользователем типов лучше передавать объекты по ссылке. Причем функции могут быть отдельно перегружены для `lvalue` ссылки и `rvalue` ссылки

Вот как, например, перегружена функция `push_back` для класса `std::vector`

```
void push_back(const T& x);
void push_back(T&& x);
```

То есть одна функция определена для константной `lvalue` ссылки вторая - для `rvalue` ссылки.

В вашем примере оператора `operator <<` также лучше объявить второй параметр как константную ссылку. В этом случае вы можете вызывать оператор для временных объектов, так как константная ссылка может "привязываться" к временным объектам: Да и сами объекты, для которых вызывается оператор,  также могут быть константными.

```
friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &stream, const three_cl &obj );
```

Для фундаментальных типов нет необходимости передавать объекты по константной ссылке вместо объектов по значению, если вы не собираетесь писать обобщенную шаблонную функцию. Например, в стандарте C++ следующие операторы `operator <<` для фундаментальных типов определены как

```
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(bool n);
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(short n);
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(unsigned short n);
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(int n);
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(unsigned int n);
// и другие операторы для фундаментальных типов
```

Как видите, аргументы передаются по значению.

Что касается возвращаемого значения, то вы должны учитывать, что нельзя возвращать ссылку из функции на локальный объект (если только он не имеет статическуй класс памяти).

Возвращение ссылки позволяет объединять вызовы нескольких функций в цепочку. Например, в классе `std::basic_string` оператор `operator +=` объявлен, как возвращающий ссылку. Благодаря этому вы можете написать, например,

```
std::string s( "Hello " );

std::cout << ( ( s += "World" ) +=  '!' ) << std::endl;
```

И это скорей вопрос не по стилю, а по эффективности и гибкости программ.:)

Comment: Спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ. Это действительно больше вопрос эффективности, но я не знал, что написать в заголовке:) Хотелось бы уточнить: `const T &var` - такой параметр функции сможет принимать как `lvalue` так и `rvalue` аргументы? И, можно ли считать универсальным(везде применимым) такой параметр: `T &&var` - ведь `rvalue` ссылки принимают также `lvalue` аргументы?

Comment: @Dim Team Когда параметр объявлен как cons T &var, то можно задавать аргумент как lvalue, так и rvale.  Для iшаблонного параметра, объявленного как T &&var, вы можете передавать lvalue. Для нешаблонного параметра вы не можете это делать.

Comment: А в этом объявлении `basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(bool n);` нужный поток не передаётся в качестве аргумента, потому что в `basic_ostream` определены все возможные потоки?

Comment: @Dim Team  Для этих типов оператор << является членом самого класса basic_ostream, а не "свободной" функцией.

Comment: А если шаблонный параметр объявлен как `const T &var` он тоже будет принимать как `lvalue` так и `rvalue`? Зачем тогда вообще `T &&var`?

Comment: @Dim Team  Да, если шаблонный параметр объявлен как const T &var  , то он может принимать как lvalue , так и  rvalue. Проблема заключается в том, какой на самом деле тип выводится для параметра на основе аргумента. Про эти правила вы можете почитать в книге Effective Modern C++: 42 Specific Ways to Improve Your Use of C++11 and C++14 (Scott Meyers, 2015)

Answer (score 0):

Например, я использую ссылки в двух случаях:

1. Для возврата значения параметру
2. Для ускорения работы (но только в крайних случаях)

Comment: `Для ускорения работы (но только в крайних случаях)` почему только в крайних, что плохого в ссылках?

Comment: Неправильно написанная функция может поменять переменную... Но это я так пишу, если скорости не важны...

Comment: @sitev_ru, передавайте ссылку на константный объект.